# How to add custom column in the product grid while creating the order in the admin in Magento 2?

Tags: product, adminhtml, sales-order, stock

I am using Magento 2.3.0

[image]

You can see above grid when you try to add products while order creation in the admin.

I want to add a new column called "Stock" in the above grid and I want to display the product's quantity in stock in this column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new column called `Stock` while creating the order in the admin need to override the class `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid` and add column `qty_in_stock`

Follow below step to create custom module to add custom column.

> Step 1)
>   magento/app/code/Venodr/SalesordercreategridStock/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_SalesordercreategridStock',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Step 2)
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/SalesordercreategridStock/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_SalesordercreategridStock" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> Step 3) magento/app/code/Vendor/SalesordercreategridStock/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" type="Vendor\SalesordercreategridStock\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" />
</config>
```

> Step 4)
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/SalesordercreategridStock/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SalesordercreategridStock\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search;

class Grid extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config $salesConfig,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        $this->_sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
        $this->_salesConfig = $salesConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $productFactory, $catalogConfig, $sessionQuote, $salesConfig, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection to be displayed in the grid
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $attributes = $this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection->setStore(
            $this->getStore()
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            $attributes
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter(
            'type_id',
            $this->_salesConfig->getAvailableProductTypes()
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'gift_message_available'
        );

        $collection->joinField(
            'qty_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1 AND {{table}}.website_id=0',
            'left'
        );

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        $parent = get_parent_class($this);
        $parentclass = get_parent_class($parent);
        return $parentclass::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare columns
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Product::class,
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'column_css_class' => 'price',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                'rate' => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
                'index' => 'price',
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Price::class
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'header' => __('Select'),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_products',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Qty::class,
                'name' => 'qty',
                'inline_css' => 'qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'qty'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty_in_stock',
            [
                'header' => __('Stock'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'qty_in_stock'
            ]
        );

        $parent = get_parent_class($this);
        $parentclass = get_parent_class($parent);
        return $parentclass::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: I am having multistore setup. Two websites one for the US and one for Canada. So for the multi-website is there any change in the above code? I asked because you used website id for joining.

Comment: Just check in your two website it is working or not. If not working then replace just that line to below code.

Replace with: 
'{{table}}.stock_id=1 AND {{table}}.website_id=0',

to

'{{table}}.stock_id=1',

Comment: worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is to create an after plugin to `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\DataProvider\ProductCollection`

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\DataProvider\ProductCollection">
    <plugin name="some_module_collection"
            type="Vendor\SomeModule\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\DataProvider\ProductCollectionPlugin"/>
</type>
```

Create the plugin class

```
class ProductCollectionPlugin
{
    public function afterGetCollectionForStore(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\DataProvider\ProductCollection $subject,
        $collection,
        \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store
    ) {
        $collection->joinField(
            'qty_in_stock',
            'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1 AND {{table}}.website_id=0',
            'left'
        );
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

You can proceed with overriding the `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid`

Then, you should only override the following method

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumn(
            'stock',
            [
                'header' => __('Stock'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'stock',
                'position' => 2
            ]
        );
        $parent = get_parent_class($this);
        $superParent = get_parent_class($parent);
        return $superParent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```